# Django rest framework in some prebuild methods , so how do I create my own method ? After creating my own method how to use it in code

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created my own method using the Django rest framework

Similar to some prebulid methods in the Django rest framework --->**get, post, and another prebulid method.**

so how can I create  my own method?

I try to create my own method, but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: The valid HTTP methods are defined in the RFCs. While you could send nearly anything as the method, it is unclear how your self-defined method will be handled by servers, client libraries, proxies, tool...

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but now I am in the learning phase.

Comment: @Sahil: I don't see how that is relevant. You can, with the HTTP protocol, only make requests as DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT and TRACE. The rest will likely get blocked somewhere along the way long before even *reaching* the Django server. Especially since such request has no "semantics" with it like idempotency, being cachable. In other words, it means nginx, the browser, etc. can not really work with it.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem 